# Connection Drupal website with SQL Google cloud database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, drupal, google-cloud-platform

I can`t find too much documentation about connecting Drupal7 website with SQL Google database. Does anybody have experience with it? I trying to split Drupal website on VM instance and mysql database on SQL Google storage. After that, change settings.php in Drupal:

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array(
'database' => 'DATABASE',
'username' => 'USERNAME',
'password' => 'PASSWORD',
'host' => 'Public_IP_of_Google_SQL',
'driver' => 'mysql',
'port' => 3306 (I try 1433 also),
'prefix' => '',
```

);
}

On SQL instance I have enabled firewall for tcp ports:3306,1433

However, I always get error 
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of /home/public_html/includes/lock.inc).

Can anybody help? What can I do on Drupal side to connect website with external database?

Comment: 1) Use the Cloud SQL Proxy and not public IP whitelisting. 2) Make sure MySQL client is connecting to Cloud SQL using the proxy. You will have better error messages to debug with. 3) Configure Drupal to connect using the same method/credentials.

Comment: How to configure Drupal to use sql proxy? Can you provide me with more details?

Comment: Complete steps #1 and #2 first. Then you will know how to connect Drupal to Cloud SQL Proxy.